# how to detect changes affected by change parents class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

By Click-event I am adding a class to the element A, that will display an element B inside the element A.
Now i want to listen on the display-change that affects element B when i add class to element A

The other way would to listen when element B is affected by style changes inside css files.

### HTML

```
<link href="...">
<div id="element-a" class="hovered">
    <span>Element B</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#element-a:not(.hovered) span {
    display:none;
}
```

Does someone know an answer?

### Update

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Mephiztopheles/n16woa38/6/
When I click on the select, the options will be shown. this event I want to catch.

Comment: Just to clarify, if someone hovers over `#element-a`, it should display `<span>Element B</span>` ??

Comment: Provide your Javascript?

Comment: I made an update for you

Comment: @JSG see the fiddle. I think this will make some clear :D